# ORA: Specified Cast Is Not Valid

Tags: oracle

Forgive me, I am new to running queries and working with databases. I am currently running what most will likely see as a very simple query, but I keep receiving an error.

My query is:

```
SELECT order, category, target_hours, actual_hours FROM ttask
```

I continually receive the error "Specified cast is not valid". By process of elimination, I've found the error to be caused by the "actual_hours" column. If I use a WHERE statement, I can get it to work on some queries but not others.

Is there a way to bypass this error? The column should have numbers with decimals in it; the query seems to return zero just fine, but anytime it actually has numbers in it, it generates this error.

There are millions of records in this database. And when querying, I want to avoid changing anything in the database.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
   at ORAQuery.Parameters.LoadQueryResult(OracleConnection conn, DataSet ds, String tableName)
   at ORAQuery.Parameters.LoadData()
   at ORAQuery.Parameters.btnLoad_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Need to see your code

Comment: Wish I knew how to give that to you.. We had someone, quite a while back, develop a query process that is ran in excel. It's not through VB.

Comment: Is it complaining about all non-zero values, or just non-integers? What data types are `target_hours` and `actual_hours`, and do they both contain non-integer values?

Comment: So, you go into Excel and run the app by clicking on a custom ribbon?  Wondering if this is some sort of VSTO addin.

Comment: Jim, yes, it is a VSTO add-in. I've just now figured out how to bypass by using the CAST function. Thank you!